# How to find all the .txt file in the li tag need multiple time clicks using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, hyperlink, tags, click

anyone know how to find all the .txt file in the li tag using python selenium, this action requires multiple time clicks to reveal the folder content. I have tried to use the  all links by all_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'). Then, using the for loop to see the return {for link in all_links:
print（link.get_attribute('href')）}. However, from the return, it seems it just finished one time click. So the directory that contains .txt files was not revealed.

I have tried to search the related answer but it seems that I have not found for my question; could anyone help me? Pls let me know if I am overlooked when there is the answer already.

[the web page and .txt file that want to be scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FrEP.png)
[the return using python selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSpWd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I addressed it by parsing the url's patterns of these .txt files with Python request and bs4. Another idea could be to use Python Scrapy.